# Как с много повторяющегося кода на js+jquery сделать короткую функцию и вызывать её в нужном месте?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Вот код с повторяющимися кусками, который никак грамотно не получается сократить, завернуть в функцию или метод. Меня почему-то заклинило, прошу помощи

```
  /*  глобальные переменные */
  var totalSumm = 0,
      protVal = 0,
      gainVal = 0,
      crea300Val = 0,
      crea500Val = 0,
      bcaa300Val = 0,
      bcaa500Val = 0,
      protWeight = 0,
      gainWeight = 0,
      crea300Weight = 0,
      crea500Weight = 0,
      bcaa300Weight = 0,
      bcaa500Weight = 0,
      fullWeight = 0,
      valWheight = 0;

  var fullAmount = function(){
    fullWeight = parseFloat(protWeight+gainWeight+crea300Weight+crea500Weight+bcaa300Weight+bcaa500Weight) * 1.1;
    switch (true) {
      case (fullWeight == 0) : valWheight =   0; break;
      case (fullWeight < 0.5): valWheight =  30; break;
      case (fullWeight < 1)  : valWheight =  35; break;
      case (fullWeight < 2)  : valWheight =  40; break;
      case (fullWeight < 5)  : valWheight =  45; break;
      case (fullWeight < 10) : valWheight =  50; break;
      case (fullWeight < 15) : valWheight =  65; break;
      case (fullWeight < 20) : valWheight =  80; break;
      case (fullWeight < 25) : valWheight =  95; break;
      case (fullWeight > 25) : valWheight = 100; break;
      default: valWheight = 45; break;
    }
    var wheyProtPrice = parseInt(priceList.wheyProt.price[protVal] || 0),
        gainerPrice = parseInt(priceList.gainer.price[gainVal] || 0),
        crea300Price = parseInt(priceList.crea300.price[crea300Val] || 0),
        crea500Price = parseInt(priceList.crea500.price[crea500Val] || 0),
        bcaa300Price = parseInt(priceList.bcaa300.price[bcaa300Val] || 0),
        bcaa500Price = parseInt(priceList.bcaa500.price[bcaa500Val] || 0);
    totalSumm = parseInt(wheyProtPrice + gainerPrice + crea300Price + crea500Price + bcaa300Price + bcaa500Price + valWheight);
    $('#summ').val(totalSumm);
  };

  var prodStart = function(){
    if($('#prot').prop('checked')){
      $('#prot').val('Да');
      if (protVal < 1){$('#prot-quantity').val('1')}
      protVal = $('#prot-quantity').val() * 1;
      protWeight = protVal * priceList.wheyProt.weightCf * 1;
    }else{
      $('#prot').val('Нет');
      protVal = 0;
      protWeight = 0;
    };
    if($('#gain').prop('checked')){
      $('#gain').val('Да');
      if (gainVal < 1){$('#gain-quantity').val('1')}
      gainVal = $('#gain-quantity').val() * 1;
      gainWeight = gainVal * priceList.gainer.weightCf * 1;
    }else{
      $('#gain').val('Нет');
      gainVal = 0;
      gainWeight = 0;
    };
    if($('#crea-300').prop('checked')){
      $('#crea-300').val('Да');
      if (crea300Val < 1){$('#crea-300-quantity').val('1')}
      crea300Val = $('#crea-300-quantity').val() * 1;
      crea300Weight = crea300Val * priceList.crea300.weightCf * 1;
    }else{
      $('#crea-300').val('Нет');
      crea300Val = 0;
      crea300Weight = 0;
    };
    if($('#crea-500').prop('checked')){
      $('#crea-500').val('Да');
      if (crea500Val < 1){$('#crea-500-quantity').val('1')}
      crea500Val = $('#crea-500-quantity').val() * 1;
      crea500Weight = crea500Val * priceList.crea500.weightCf * 1;
    }else{
      $('#crea-500').val('Нет');
      crea500Val = 0;
      crea500Weight = 0;
    };
    if($('#bcaa-300').prop('checked')){
      $('#bcaa-300').val('Да');
      if (bcaa300Val < 1){$('#bcaa-300-quantity').val('1')}
      bcaa300Val = $('#bcaa-300-quantity').val() * 1;
      bcaa300Weight = bcaa300Val * priceList.bcaa300.weightCf * 1;
    }else{
      $('#bcaa-300').val('Нет');
      bcaa300Val = 0;
      bcaa300Weight = 0;
    };
    if($('#bcaa-500').prop('checked')){
      $('#bcaa-500').val('Да');
      if (bcaa500Val < 1){$('#bcaa-500-quantity').val('1')}
      bcaa500Val = $('#bcaa-500-quantity').val() * 1;
      bcaa500Weight = bcaa500Val * priceList.bcaa500.weightCf * 1;
    }else{
      $('#bcaa-500').val('Нет');
      bcaa500Val = 0;
      bcaa500Weight = 0;
    };
  };

  prodStart();
  fullAmount();

  $('#prot, #gain, #crea-300, #crea-500, #bcaa-300, #bcaa-500, #prot-quantity, #gain-quantity, #crea-300-quantity, #crea-500-quantity, #bcaa-300-quantity, #bcaa-500-quantity').change(function(){
    prodStart(this);
    fullAmount();
  });
```

Comment: html код тоже приложите, пожалуйста.

Comment: И явно не хватает `priceList`

Comment: ни html, ни priceList ничем не поможет сократить код

Comment: @reFactorPro, нужна структура `priceList`: какие поля есть в этом объекте? только те, которые показаны в коде или еще какие-то?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) `fullWeight == 0` - плохо, т.к. нестрогое сравнение. Если в `fullWeight` будет строка со значение `"0"`, то будет `true`. Нужно строгое сравнение использовать `fullWeight === 0`.

2) Как минимум, весь `prodStart` можно переписать, если вместо текущего задания переменных задать их одним объектом:

```
var globalVars = {
    totalSumm : 0,
    protVal : 0,
    gainVal : 0,
    crea300Val : 0,
    crea500Val : 0,
    bcaa300Val : 0,
    bcaa500Val : 0,
    protWeight : 0,
    gainWeight : 0,
    crea300Weight : 0,
    crea500Weight : 0,
    bcaa300Weight : 0,
    bcaa500Weight : 0,
    fullWeight : 0,
    valWheight : 0
};
```

А сам метод переписать так:

```
var prodStart = function(){
    doThings("prot", "wheyProt");
    doThings("gain", "gainer");
    doThings("crea-300", "crea300");
    doThings("crea-500", "crea500");
    doThings("bcaa-300", "bcaa300");
    doThings("bcaa-500", "bcaa500");
};

function doThings(key, listKey) {
    var varKey = key.replace("-", "");
    var jKey = '#' + key;
    var jqkey = '#' + key + '-quantity';
    var valKey = key + "Val";
    var weightKey = key + "Weight";

    if ($(jKey).prop('checked')) {
        $(jKey).val('Да');
        if (globalVars[varKey] < 1)
            $(jqkey).val('1');

        globalVars[valKey] = $(jqkey).val() * 1;
        globalVars[weightKey] = globalVars[valKey] * priceList[listKey].weightCf * 1;
    } else {
        $(jKey).val('Нет');
        globalVars[valKey] = 0;
        globalVars[weightKey] = 0;
    }
}
```

Остаётся только `fullAmount` слегка переписать.

Т.к. html разметки не привели в вопросе, то проверить не могу. Но, как минимум, думаю, ход мысли понятен будет.